# XPath query for getting the right element

Tags: xml, xpath

What XPath Query will get me the role id of the role that has a subelement with a name element "Participant"... i.e. the answer i want is 11. How do I get that answer using XPath on this XML?

`

API_GetRoleInfo
0
No error

 
  Viewer
  Basic Access
 
 
  Participant
  Basic Access
  
 
  Administrator
 Administrator
 

`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//role[name = 'Participant']/@id
```